# iOS Speech framework yields zero confidence for certain locales

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition

When using the Speech framework, I am consistently noticing zero confidence values for certain locales (e.g. "vi-VN", "pt-PT", ...), while non-zero, accurate confidence values are returned for other locales (e.g. "ko-KR", "ja-JP", ...).

Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sftranscriptionsegment/1649534-confidence), the confidence would be zero if there was no recognition. However, when the zero confidence occurs, the `formattedString` of the `bestTranscription` is populated and accurate (same for each segment substring text).

I have tried instantiating the locales in various ways (language code only, language and region code, -/_ formatting, grabbing an instance directly off of the `SFSpeechRecognizer.supportedLocales()` array). I have also tried setting the `defaultTaskHint` of `SFSpeechRecognizer` and taskHint of `SFSpeechRecognitionRequest` to dictation.

I am stuck at this point. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

```
guard let locale = Locale(identifier: "vi-VN"),
      let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: locale),
      recognizer.isAvailable else {
  return
}

recognizer.defaultTaskHint = .dictation

let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: ...)
request.contextualStrings = ...
request.shouldReportPartialResults = true
request.taskHint = .dictation
    
recognizer.recognitionTask(with: request) { (result, error) in
  ...
  if (result.isFinal) {
    let transcription = result.bestTranscription
    /// transcription.formattedString is correct
    /// all segments confidence values are 0, but with the properly recognized substring text.
  }
  ...
}
```